# In MQTT, how does the broker get notified of a client's Last Will and Testament?

Tags: mqtt

**Problem:**
If everything in MQTT is pubsub but it feels like for Last Will and Testament (LWT) to work there would have to be Long polling from some end?

**Question:**
In MQTT, How does broker know when a client goes off line? 
And what's the flow on LWT notifying the broker, is it long polling?

[last will test documentation](http://eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/february/article2.php)

> **Last Will And Testament MQTT** clients can register a custom “last will
>   and testament” message to be sent by the broker if they disconnect.
>   These messages can be used to signal to subscribers when a device
>   disconnects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MQTT protocol has a keep alive time that is set at connection time. If there is no messages published by the client in that time the client will send a pong packet to the server. If the server does not get a publish or a ping in the time it marks the client as disconnected and delivers the LWT message to any other clients subscribed to the relevant topic.

Comment: I'd like just to add that the server waits for the PING packet within one and a half times the Keep Alive time period specified in the CONNECT packet (the server gives more time to the client). You have the same behavior if the client brutally close the connection (ex. RST packet on TCP layer). Remember ... the last will message isn't sent if the client sends a DISCONNECT message.

Answer (score 4):

MQTT has a keep alive mechanism (which is essentially a heartbeat). When a client connects, the keep alive value for that specific client can be specified. If the client is idle for one and a half the time specified and does not send any heartbeat or any other MQTT message, the broker assumes the TCP connection is broken (= half-open).

The HiveMQ MQTT Essentials Blog Series has in-depth articles of the LWT and keep-alive mechanisms:

- [MQTT Essentials Part 9 - Last Will and Testament](http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-essentials-part-9-last-will-and-testament/)
- [MQTT Essentials Part 10: Keep Alive and Client Take-Over](http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-essentials-part-10-alive-client-take-over/)